# Boot from external eSATA

Tags: usb

An HP laptop has [eSATA port](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/peripherals/thunderbolt-vs-usb-3-0-vs-esata-931343) (doubles as a USB port) and USB 2.0 ports.  No UEFI.  I would like the ability to boot from an external SSD and not have to disassemble the laptop.  Assuming that the BIOS supports selection of the eSATA port,

- Must the [SSD enclosure explicitly support eSATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M0SLHJ1) confer eSATA bandwidth?
- If using an SSD is it unnecessary to have an a wall-wart to power the drive?

The first question is posed because the eSata drive works doubles as a USB port.  **If you have experience booting from an external eSATA device: please state this along with any lessons-learned. Double bonus round: using an external SSD and stating the enclosure details. Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using that exact model with a 256G SSD on an ESATA port, but I do use the external power supply.  It outperforms my internal hard disk on the Lenovo to which it is attached.  The intall and boot was without problems, no particular lessons learned, everything went as expected.